# Connect Oracle DB through RStudio using RODBC

Tags: r, database, oracle, rstudio, rodbc

I might be re-asking the question but I am having difficulty creating connection to Oracle DB which is on a remote server. I am new to R and Oracle DB so I do not have much experience. I am using RStudio. I have installed RODBC package successfully. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 Operating System.
Firstly I use library RODBC

`library("RODBC", lib.loc="~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0")`

Then I have entered following command:

`odbcConnect(dsn = "DatabaseName", uid = "UserID", pwd = "Password")`

I get the following error:

`[1] -1
Warning messages:
1: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=DatabaseName;UID=UserID;PWD=Password") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
2: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=DatabaseName;UID=UserID;PWD=Password") :
  ODBC connection failed`

I have searched but I am not getting to anywhere. Please tell me process or steps to how I can make a connection.

Thank You!

Comment: Are you really sure you created a DSN prior to this connection named with the same name as your database? Check all your sources: `odbcDataSources()` Do you see your DSN or driver?

Comment: Yes I have put same database name I am working on. I tried `odbcDataSources("all")` and I got `named character(0)`. I do not know further details about DSN or Driver. I am supposed to connect to remover server Oracle DB and I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: Should I be putting more details like ip address or host URL to connect it directly from my system? I do not have database in my system or anything else because I want to make a direct connection.

Comment: That means you have no drivers/DSNs set up on machine. Unlike other DB APIs, RODBC requires a driver installed beforehand. You need to install the Oracle Linux ODBC driver. And a Data Source Name (DSN) is a separate file you create (referencing a driver) to serve as a shortcut with all server/database/user/password details. ODBC also tends to be a Windows technology, not fully fluid in other OS's. Check out [ROracle](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROracle/index.html) package, no other installs needed.

Comment: Thanks Parfait. I will try check it and update.